# Having trouble in GridView Layout

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-gridview

I have this Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.anandvardhan.albumview040416.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/grid_view"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:numColumns="2"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#fff">
    </GridView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But now I am getting a preview like this:

[image: But now I am getting a preview like this:]

So how to select an item at position 1, because it must be beneath the toolbar.

And one more thing.

If my GridView is initially empty then it must show a TextView in centre of the 
screen stating "It's Empty". How to set it dynamically.

I will be very thankful if anyone could help.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve `GridView` item at position 1 in `XML`?

Comment: @Aks4125 : By default it should start from Item 1 only. But in preview it is showing from Item 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if you have any question,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.anandvardhan.albumview040416.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <GridView android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#fff"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:numColumns="2">
        </GridView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Really Thanks Man. You saved my day.

Comment: @AnandVardhan no problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView and set Layout Manager as GridLayoutManager.

Here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.anandvardhan.albumview040416.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<!-- Your Empty view here -->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/button_background_dark_red"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

To use GridLayoutManager with RecyclerView, please check [this site](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

If there's no data, you can set the visibility of RecyclerView to View.GONE and set the visibility of empty view to View.VISIBLE

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and notify you asap.